# Panic in Golang http.Client with high concurrent excecutions

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, go

I am creating a system which is a http server in golang that will perform several request to another API based in every request that come to it.

e.g

```
curl localhost:8080/users?ids=1,2,3,4
```

will perform several concurrent gets to:

```
api.com/user/1

api.com/user/2

api.com/user/3

api.com/user/4
```

I am having a problem, the http.Client is getting my a panic, when it has a heavy concurrent requests (if I hit localhost:8080/users?ids=1,2,3,4.....40 with AB with 4 concurrent, or hitting refresh in my browser)

The proglem appears to be with the sentence (line 159)

```
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
```

My code is here (Not so large... 180 lines):
http://play.golang.org/p/olibNz2n1Z

The panic error is this one:

```
goroutine 5 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).roundTrip(0xc210058f80, 0xc21000a720, 0xc210058f80, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/transport.go:879 +0x6d6
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc210058280, 0xc21005b1a0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/transport.go:187 +0x391
net/http.send(0xc21005b1a0, 0x590290, 0xc210058280, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/client.go:168 +0x37f
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc21001e960, 0xc21005b1a0, 0x28, 0xc21001ec30, 0xc21005f570)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/client.go:100 +0xd9
net/http.(*Client).doFollowingRedirects(0xc21001e960, 0xc21005b1a0, 0x2ab298, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/client.go:294 +0x671
net/http.(*Client).Do(0xc21001e960, 0xc21005b1a0, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/client.go:129 +0x8f
main.buscarRecurso(0xc21000a650, 0xb, 0xc2100526c0)
    /Users/fscasserra/Documents/workspace/Luna/multiget-api/multiget.go:159 +0x131
created by main.obtenerRecursos
    /Users/fscasserra/Documents/workspace/Luna/multiget-api/multiget.go:106 +0x197
```

Can anyone help me?

Best regards,
Fer

Comment: Panic occur in goroutine with status `running`. Those who with status `select` just sleep.

Comment: ...its not thrown from a panic? ...

Comment: You've shown what goroutine 5's stack looks like. What about all the other goroutines? Are you sure goroutine 5 is the one that panicked?

Comment: What is the panic message?

Comment: For starters: check the errors returned by http.NewRequest and client.Do. Your application ignores them and continues.

Comment: Check all other errors to. You are also ignoring ioutil.ReadAll. (And writing "normal" godoc comments would make reading your code more pleasant :-)

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in the defer function, I was not checked if the response was nil before closing it.

Answer (score 2):

I will put money on the panic coming from calling `Close()` on a nil `resp.Body`.

**Always check your errors!**

In general, if a function returns a value and an error, the response value may not be usable in the case of a non-nil error. Any exceptions to this should be well documented.

Comment: Yeap, I found that the error is produced by Close() on a resp.Body in the defer function.:panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x3295]

Comment: @Fersca: don't do that. The response isn't valid if there was an error, so even if `resp != nil`, `Body` (or other attributes) may still contain a nil pointer.